# How to de-select a JList when I click anywhere else?

Tags: java, swing

I have JList filled with items. When I click on one item and then I click away, the item is still selected. My intuition says that the item should be de-selected. Is there a simple way to do this?

What I thought to solve this, is to attach a mouse-adapter to the JList so that whenever I click on the JList then clearSelection() is called. But wouldn't that interfere with selecting an item from the list too?

Comment: "My intuition says that the item should be de-selected" Why? This is by design so that you can fill in multiple different inputs in a form to be processed.  That said, your proposed solution should work if you really do want to do this

Comment: @StormeHawke I do want that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behavior for the component. Adding another `MouseListener` will not interfere with the functionality of the `JList`

```
list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
        list.clearSelection();
    }
});
```

Comment: that didn't work. I clicked anywhere and the item in the list is still selected.

Comment: when I use another component, your way works (like pressing another button or so). But clicking anywhere doesn't work. I just attached a FocusListener as you did exactly.

Comment: The question didnt state that the list was the only component. In that case there's no problem adding another MouseListener as you're just listening for mouseExited - mouse clicks will still work :)

Answer (score 1):

If you select something in the list and go away, the list element should keep selection. If you want something else, you should use `FocusListener`

Something like this:

```
list.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
  public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    JList list = (JList) e.getComponent();
    list.clearSelection();
  }
});
```